# Using templates to query ElasticSearch with R

Tags: r, elasticsearch

First, I start a connection:

```
connect(es_host = "172.19.28.5")
```

And then search for my template (the template name’s `getKpiHistMetric`):

```
Search_template_get('getKpiHistMetric')
```

And the result is:

```
>$lang
[1] "mustache"

$`_id`
[1] "getKpiHistMetric"

$found
[1] TRUE

$`_version`
[1] 2

$template
[1] "{"size": 1000,
    "query": {
      "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {"term":{"KpiKey":"{{KpiKey}}"}},
              {"range":{"HistWriteTimestamp":{
                                             "from":"{{from}}",
                                             "to":"{{to}}"
                                             }
                       }
              }]
   }}}}}"
```

So, I can reach the server and find the template query. This template has three parameters: `KpiKey`, `from` and `to`. How can I query the database using this template? What function is to be used? And how do I pass the parameters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a reproducible example

```
library(elastic)
conntect()
```

Load `iris` dataset into ES

```
if (!index_exists("iris")) {
  invisible(docs_bulk(iris, "iris"))
}
```

Make a template

```
body <- '{
  "template": {
     "query": {
         "match": {
             "Species": "{{query_string}}"
         }
     }
   }
}'
```

Register the template

```
Search_template_register(template = 'foobar', body = body)
```

Define a search, using the template name as defined in `Search_template_register`,

```
body2 <- '{
 "id": "foobar",
    "params": {
      "query_string": "setosa"
  }
}'
```

Search the template with `Search_template`

```
Search_template(body = body2)
```

- with Elaticsearch `v5.0.0`, R `v3.3.2`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will accept it. Can you please point me where to look further on how to create the code inside `body` and `body2` variables?

Comment: the body can be an R list or JSON, the  `elastic` docs have example of each. see Elastic docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/search-template.html for examples